# fully absolute positioned layout shows up blank

Tags: css, css-position

I'm working on a website and have been using absolute positioning, since the viewport size will always be fixed (offline iphone webapp). Halfway through I realized that I wasn't using a proper doctype declaration and such. When I added those and refreshed in a browser, the content completely vanished.

A code sample is below. With no doctype and a plain "" opening html tag, the content shows up. As it is below, the page shows up completely blank. Can anyone explain why this doesn't this code work in standards mode (with doctype and such)? What can I change to fix it (preferably cross browser compatible) - while still using an absolute positioned layout?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        html {
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div style="position: absolute; visibility: visible; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; z-index: -1; top: 0; height: 480; left: 0; width: 320; text-align: left; " class="windowWrapper">
        <div style="position: absolute; visibility: visible; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; z-index: 0; top: 0; height: 480; left: 0; width: 320; text-align: left; " class="mobilePage">
            <div style="position: absolute; visibility: visible; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; z-index: 0; top: 0; height: 50; left: 0; width: 320; text-align: left; " class="mobileToolbar">
                <button style="position: absolute; visibility: visible; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; z-index: 0; top: 5; height: 40; left: 5; width: 60; text-align: center; " class="">Back</button>
                <button style="position: absolute; visibility: visible; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; z-index: 0; top: 5; height: 40; left: 245; width: 70; text-align: center; " class="">Options</button>
                <p style="position: absolute; visibility: visible; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; z-index: 0; top: 5; height: 40; left: 65; width: 180; text-align: center; " class="mobilePageTitle">Home</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add "px" after your height and width measurements to indicate the size in pixels, the page should display better.

eg. `width: 300px;`

The strict standards mode will be more stringent about needing you to specify these type of things correctly.

You can use the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to validate web pages for correctness against the standards and i suspect it would highlight these kind of issues.

Comment: Thanks!!!!! That worked like a charm! I had looked at some other examples and just couldn't figure out what I was doing that was different. I'll remember the validator in the future...